# How to display data from backend with a Promise() in Angular?

Tags: angular, express, promise, angular-fullstack

I would like to display a page from my Backend to my Angular frontend.

Backend: at 'http://localhost:8080/test' I display a simple "hello" text.

Frontend: at 'http://localhost:4200/editeur' there's a button. When I click on the button, I would like to display my 'http://localhost:8080/test' content under the button (so my "hello" text in this case).

I used a Promise() in Angular.

This is my Express backend middleware:

```
server.use('/test', (req, res, next) => {
res.json({ message: 'Hello' });
console.log('Hello');
next();
});
```

This is my HTML frontend:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" (click)="getEditeur()">Display backend</button>
```

This is my TS Angular frontend:

```
getEditeur() {

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/test').subscribe(
    (response) => {
      resolve(response);
    },
    (error) => {
      reject(error);
    }
  );
});
}
```

When I click the button, the console.log('Hello'); from my backend works, so frontend and backend are well linked. But now I would like my Promise() to display on screen the `res.json({ message: 'Hello' });` message.

Thanks !

Comment: Are you getting any error ? if yes kindly post the error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use async pipe , check this example

component

```
  data = null
  i = 1;

  getEditeur() {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // call the api => 
      // get the result ... 
      resolve({ message: 'Hello', times: this.i++ });
    });
  }

  getData() {
    this.data = this.getEditeur();
  }
```

template

```
<button (click)="getData()">Click</button>

<pre>
  {{data | async | json}}
</pre>

<ng-container *ngIf="data | async  as messageData">
  <div>message from server {{messageData.message}} , times {{messageData.times}}</div>
</ng-container>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jdggxw)

> everytime you click the button will act to give nre promise after this promise resolve the data will be render by json pipe that why I add times property

Without async pipe you can use **async/await**

```
  async getData() {
    this.data = await this.getEditeur();
  }
```

[demo ⚡⚡](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6thks8)

finally you can use promise then method

```
  getData() {
    this.getEditeur().then(result=> this.data = result);
  }
```

check this [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: Thank you. You answered my question with your first option, but it only works with Json objects. The final purpose is to display an object displayed on the backend which is not a Json object - This is an editor created by my backend with a Node server. How could I display it ? Thank you !

Comment: you are welcome happy to help , I have updated the async pipe section and the live demo 

Comment: check the ng-container @Théo.G

Answer (score 3):

I believe your getEditeur function can be simplified by using [Observable.toPromise](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/topromise.html)

```
getEditeur() {
   return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/test').toPromise()
}
```

Comment: This is the correct way and should be the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

you can access the promise response from API like below

```
getData() {
 this.getEditeur().then(res=>{
   //use res as response from api
    this.data = res;
 }).catch(error =>{
   console.log(error);
  });
}
```

modified of https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56560723/revisions

Comment: hi , you need to move this.data to the body of then